# Magento 1.9 checkout doesn't display country dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, magento-1.9, checkout

I can't seem to make Magento checkout to work. The country dropdown is not showing. This is linked to `getCountryHtmlSelect('billing');` and when i `var_dump` it i get `string(0) ""` . I have already set specific countries to display for as dropdown, but nothing seems to work. I also get some javascript errors as well

```
form.js:178 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null
at klass.initialize (form.js:178)
at klass (prototype.js:80)
at (index):1131
```

with line number 178 `if (this.regionSelectEl.options.length<=1)`

Any suggestions? Thnaks

Comment: It looks like it can't find the region select field. Did you perhaps remove it from your templates because you don't need it?

Comment: Hello the field for region select is there in the template. /app/design/frontend/davids/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml . It's from where i debug the template from but still nothing. I also changed the options to All countries in Shipping Methods, Shipping Settings and the Configuration->General Optons and nothing again is displayed.